# go back to the previous page after changing the data in for in php

Tags: javascript, php

i am trying to redirect the page to previous page after edit the form..

i have these two url's for example

http://localhost/******/viewclientadmin.php?id=14

and

http://localhost/****/clientadminedit.php?id=106

so client after edit the form i want them to redirect to the viewclientadmin page

i already tried like this

```
if($DB->execute($chk_qry,$parms)) {  
 header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
 }
```

but it's not going back..it staying  on same page..

can you please help me out..how to do that..

thanks in advance...

Comment: have you tried this header("Location: http://localhost/***.php?$qry");

Comment: like how i didn't understand

Comment: I was saying you should use if($DB->execute($chk_qry,$parms)) {  
 header("Location: localhost***.php?$qry");
 } instead of history.go by this way you will get your id on viewclientadmin and using that Id you will be able to fetch data from db and assign to your form. let's know if that works or not :)

Comment: can you please make it as answer so it will be more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your url in session like this and call that variable in another page in header

In your viewclientadmin.php page add these two lines

```
$page = "viewclientadmin.php?id=$id";
$_SESSION['page'] = $page;
```

And in your clientadminedit.php page add like this

```
if($DB->execute($chk_qry,$parms)) { 

  header("Location: " . $_SESSION['page']);
}
```

it will work...try

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if($DB->execute($chk_qry,$parms)) { 
    header("Location: localhost***.php?$qry"); 
}
```

Instead of `history.go` by this way you will get your id on viewclientadmin and using that Id you will be able to fetch data from db and assign to your form.

Comment: so in which page i have to use like this edither view page or edit page

Comment: it's going to the view page but it showing error Undefined index: id in E:\xampp\htdocs\mooglms\custom\viewclientadmin.php on line 7

Comment: i have that code in clientadminedit page so i kept your code in edit page only